# ExtentReports .jar file is not working if we create user library in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Is there another way to create User library in eclipse (Java)? I created my own library, and I added an Extent Report supported `.jar` file. But every time it displays Null pointer error for releventextent report, once I remove it from my own library. If I configured the build path separately for only extent report it worked fine.

Comment: So... add your own library without the reference to Extent Report? Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is a quick and useful checklist to elevate your English communication skills.